# Width of child element is able to override max-width set by parent element. How can I prevent this from happening?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create 3 columns layout template with fixed ratio per each column based on size of view port so 20% for left, 50% for center body content and 30% for right. I also have set minimum and maximum width per each column in pixels under parent containers. But problem I'm facing is when I add `width:400px` to child-left, it ignores the max-width of parent-left(320px) and stretch out the width of left nav to 400px. I was hoping child element to respect the max-width set by parent. How can I set the max/min-width of each column so that no matter what width I put in child element, it respects the width percent and max/min-width of parent element?

```css
* {
  outline: 1px red solid;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.parent-left {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 320px;
  min-width: 256px;
}
.parent-center {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 1400px;
}
.parent-right {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 464px;
  min-width: 384px;
}
.child-left {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width: 400px; /*I don't want this to over-ride max-width of 320px, but it does.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="parent-left">
    <nav class="child-left">
      <p>Left Nav</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-center">
    <div class="child-center">
      <p>Body Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-right">
    <div class="child-right">
      <p>Right Panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `max-width: 100%;` in addition to width on child. Alternatively: `width: min(400px, 100%);` on the child. Also: `overflow: hidden;` or `overflow: scroll;` on parent. Also look at `flex` and `grid` layout techniques instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Chase for idea

```css
* {
  outline: 1px red solid;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.parent-left {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 320px;
  min-width: 256px;
}
.parent-center {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 1400px;
}
.parent-right {
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 464px;
  min-width: 384px;
}
.child-left {
  background-color: hotpink;
  max-width: 100%;/*if u use less than 100% it works but more means set back to 100% that's available space by parent*/
  width: 400px; /*I don't want this to over-ride max-width of 320px, but it does.*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="parent-left">
    <nav class="child-left">
      <p>Left Nav</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-center">
    <div class="child-center">
      <p>Body Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-right">
    <div class="child-right">
      <p>Right Panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    * {
  outline: 1px red solid;
  margin: 0;
}
.parent-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.parent-left {
  flex:1;
  max-width:320px;
}
.parent-center {
flex:3;
  
}
.parent-right {
 flex:2;
  
}
.child-left {
  background-color: hotpink;
  width:100%
   /*I don't want this to over-ride max-width of 320px, but it does.*/
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="parent-wrapper">
  <div class="parent-left">
    <nav class="child-left">
      <p>Left Nav</p>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-center">
    <div class="child-center">
      <p>Body Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-right">
    <div class="child-right">
      <p>Right Panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

; /*I don't want this to over-ride max-width of 320px, but it does.*/
}

Comment: Is flex: 1 equivalent to width:20% of the screen? Using flex, how can I accurately divide the columns to 20%, 50%, 30% ratio?